# How do I improve ASP.Net MVC3 performance on each page's first hit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

If I make a change to a razor view, recompile, or wait 15-20 minutes, a page might take anywhere from 3-20 seconds to render on that first hit.  I understand that the view needs to be recompiled after a change.  I also understand that the application will be unloaded after a period of inactivity, but I thought that would be a one time penalty on the very first hit.  But for me it seems to apply to every single page.

Take, as an example, my homepage.  According to YSlow it's a "B" with 15 components and weighing 250K (that's including MiniProfiler's extra jquery reference).  From MiniProfiler I see about 500ms on the first line (http://localhost:80).  I'm assuming this includes the view compilation.  But then I see 1200ms for Find:Index.  There are no SQL calls.  Total load time on the first hit is about 3000ms, subsequent hits are about 40ms.

On another page with a couple of partial views, the parent view takes 2400ms to "Find", one of the partial views takes 1000ms to find.  The parent view also takes 3200ms to "Render".  And the biggest impact is on the first line (http://localhost:80/User/Dashboard) which was a whopping 7000ms.  This page has only 3 queries with a total query time of 100ms.  The total time to load was more than 15000ms. Subsequent hits are about 250ms.

Our setup is ASP.Net MVC 3, Ninject, EF4.2, Razor view engine, ELMAH, NLog, Html5Boilerplate, and MvcMiniProfiler.  I created a duplicate project and removed Ninject, ELMAH, NLog, and MvcMiniProfiler.  Performance was only marginally faster.  We have about 15 controllers and about 40 views, all in one area.

Is this normal performance?  When we deploy to Azure, it's even worse (naturally) than testing locally.  Are there suggestions for improvement?

**Edit:**
A first hit after compile on IIS/localhost (in release mode and with compilation debug=false) can be about 15 seconds. The Azure deployment, running in release, has a faster first hit, but still in the range of 5-10 seconds. I tried David Ebbo's project but didn't see anything dramatic.

Comment: Doesn't sound like normal performance.  Those times are atrocious.  I have a very large MVC project with far more controllers and views, spanning 11 class libraries + the final MVC project.  My views (some with *many* partial views) rarely take longer than 20ms on the first-hit (and that includes database calls), and average around 9ms afterwards.

Comment: Check this out: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html

Comment: @tugberk, yup.. I use precompiled views also.  However, I still wouldn't expect the performance-drain that Donald is experiencing.

Comment: To be clear, you are running in release, right? Not debug builds?

Comment: A first hit after compile on IIS/localhost (in release mode and with compilation debug=false) can be about 15 seconds.  The Azure deployment, running in release, has a faster first hit, but still in the range of 5-10 seconds.  I tried David Ebbo's project but didn't see anything dramatic.

Comment: if you render many partial views on a page, it's best to specify the whole virtual path like `~/Views/....` so MVC doesn't have to "search" for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you deploy this application frequently? If so, then I can see why the first hit performance can be of concern.

We deploy often, and have created a separate project to "warm up" our deployments. It is a unit test project that uses WebDriver to hit each uncompiled view in our app after it is deployed.

Basically, you just use the WebDriver API to fire up a browser, then Navigate() to each URL that needs compiled. Run it once, and the deployment is warm.

Also, in Azure, you can turn off the idle timeout, so that your app never gets idled. We use this script:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

... and run it during the Azure deployment like so:

```
  <Task commandLine="startup\disableTimeout.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
```

Comment: Our app is still "alpha" so we're doing a lot of deployments.  It's more frustration from the long cycle of making a minor change to a view and then waiting 10 seconds to see if that was the right tweak.

Comment: I'll definitely have to turn off the idle timeout on Azure, as well as implement a warmup project.